# Creating 1000 markers on Google Map constitutes towards API Call

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I would like to know, if I am given with 1000 (x,y) coordinates where each pair (x,y) represents a customer address

if I have to load 1000 address as marker with their coordinates (lat, long) on top of map, will each marker set through method createMarker(x,y,message) will constitutes towards api call.

My primary concern is : If given with 30000 address and I try to drop pin for each address will I be touching API on single map load.

Please advice

Comment: What do you mean, "touching API"? Creating a marker at a given lat/long can be done as many times as you want without reaching any API limits.

Comment: My bad, I mean to say touching API call limits

Answer (score 1):

No, each marker does not count as an API call.  You can load however many markers you want, the thing that counts is the load of the API script.  Services like the geocoder, have quotas and rate limits but don't count towards your API Quota ([described here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/usage))

Answer (score 0):

That can be done using KML's (which is a xml).single call will load all the markers.

go through this link https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/mapsSupport